# When would you use Client Side Rendering VS. Server Side Rendering?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to React and wondering when someone would use:

**1. Server Side Rendering**
**2. Client Side Rendering**

With React and Django Rest Framework. What causes something to be better with one or the other? Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand, you would want to use SSR if you have a lot of JS? But not fully sure.

Comment: @RahulRentash that's what I was thinking but was not fully sure. I'm sure there are other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This list tries to be a brief overview on some of the trade offs here.

### Search Engine Optimization

With client side rendering, when you view the source of a page, your entire React app is going to a something like `<div id="root"></div>`.

In the past, search engines wouldn't be able to crawl any of that React content. Today, search engines like Google *are* able to crawl that content, so this is becoming less of a reason to server side render. Checkout [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics) for more. This is also a [great talk](https://youtu.be/3B7gBVTsEaE) on the topic.

### First Contentful Paint (aka Performance)

For large apps, there could be noticeable difference in the time it takes for the browser to first show something to the user. For more on that, see [this article](https://web.dev/first-contentful-paint/).

### Data

If your app needs to fetch data when the app is first mounted, you may show a loading spinner to users while before that data is received. Another alternative is to server side render the app and make that request on the server. Then, the top level React component could receive that data as props that would be available when the app is first mounted.

### Complexity

Server side rendering is an added complexity that may not be needed for some projects. As software engineers, it could be argued that we're responsible for reducing complexity wherever possible, and choosing to client side render should be the default option until you face issues that warrant the added complexity that comes with server side rendering.

Comment: Thanks so much for this response! Just to confirm, I am currently building a dashboard with tons of CRUD. Which approach would you recommend for this? Thank you sooo much!!

Comment: Also, would you happen to be familiar with Next.js and React?

Comment: Also wondering how Next.js fits into the picture!

Comment: My pleasure! Even for a CRUD app, I would choose to client side render until I face issues there. Many would not face any such issues.

Comment: I haven't used Next.js before, but I've evaluated it for various projects. Since I'm biased towards minimizing dependencies and am comfortable with the configuration details of a project, I've always chosen to not use Next.js. Next.js takes care of a bunch of configuration including SSR, so if you'd like to get SSR without having to learn about configuration, Next.js can be a good choice. Personally, I prefer learning from the basics myself and adding complexity as needed than starting with unneeded complexity in the hopes that I'll need it later